# AfterSuite is getting skipped in testng

Tags: selenium-webdriver

AfterSuite is not working properly. I have 2 test cases which extends base test.
When the first test case of before method is skipping then aftersuite is not getting executed. Aftersuite is also skipping.
Is this is bug or expected behaviour?
My requirement is I want to run some statements after all test case executed.
Below is the code for the test cases.

Base test

```
package suiteone;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class BaseTest  {

    @BeforeSuite
    public void BeforeSuite() throws Exception{

        System.out.println("before suite");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void AfterSuite() throws Exception{

        System.out.println("After suite");
    }

}
```

First test case

```
package suiteone;

import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FirstTestCase extends BaseTest{

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {    
        System.out.println("before method of "+this.getClass().getName());
        throw new SkipException("Skipping the test case "); 

    }


    @Test
    public void FirstTestCase() {

        System.out.println("I am in test case "+this.getClass().getName());


    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() { 
        System.out.println("after method of "+this.getClass().getName());
    }

}
```

Second test case

```
package suiteone;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SecondTestCase extends BaseTest{

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod()  {   
        System.out.println("before method of "+this.getClass().getName());

    }


    @Test
    public void SecondTestCase() {

        System.out.println("I am in test case "+this.getClass().getName());


    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod()   {   
        System.out.println("after method of "+this.getClass().getName());
    }

}
```

Testng xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite one">

  <test name="test">
      <classes>
      <class name="suiteone.FirstTestCase"/>
      <class name="suiteone.SecondTestCase"/>
      </classes>   
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

When i executed testng.xml file before suite method is printed, but not after suite.

My query is, Is this bug or expected behavior. How to make that aftersuite also get printed.
Below is the output which is displayed in console. (I m using testng 6.12, webdriver 3.5.3)

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.12.0
before suite
before method of suiteone.FirstTestCase
before method of suiteone.SecondTestCase
I am in test case suiteone.SecondTestCase
after method of suiteone.SecondTestCase

===============================================
Suite one
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 0, Skips: 3
===============================================
```

Answer (score 3):

May not, in any case place correct your `@AfterSuite` as `@AfterSuite(alwaysRun=true)`
in this case you `@AfterSuite` will be executed even in case of a failure.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!

Comment: Hi can you explain what do you mean by failure? Is if failure of any '@Test method in any one of the classes specified in any of the <test>  within that suit?. I my case all the methods are passing by still my '@AfterSuit is not running without alwaysRun=true

Comment: Also is this applicable only to @AfterSuite

Comment: I have @AfterSuite(alwaysRun=true) but my suite hangs after the last test case and won't go into the AfterSuite.  Any suggestions?